# How to use a dictionary of dictionaries as output from Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

This function is driving me insane!

```
def CCAD1 (tree)
    leaves = []
    for otu in tree:
        if tree[otu][2]== None and tree[otu][1]== None:
                leaves += [otu]
    ccad = {}
    for leaf in leaves:
            otuX = leaf
            otu1 = leaf
            for leaf2 in leaves:
                otuY = leaf2
                otu2 = leaf2
                while tree[otu1][0] is not None and tree[otu2][0] is not None and tree[otu1][0][0] != tree[otu2][0][0]:
                        otu1,otu2,tree = tree[otu1][0][0],tree[otu2][0][0],tree
                if tree[otu1][0] is not None:
                    ccad[otuX] = {otuY:tree[otu1][0]}
    return ccad
```

This is the input to the function

```
{'A': [('AD', 4.0), None, None], 'C': [('ADBFGC', 14.5), None, None], 'B': [('BF', 0.5), None, None], 'E': [('ADBFGCE', 17.0), None, None], 'D': [('AD', 4.0), None, None], 'G': [('BFG', 6.25), None, None], 'F': [('BF', 0.5), None, None], 'ADBFG': [('ADBFGC', 6.25), ('AD', 4.25), ('BFG', 2.0)], 'BF': [('BFG', 5.75), ('B', 0.5), ('F', 0.5)], 'ADBFGC': [('ADBFGCE', 2.5), ('ADBFG', 6.25), ('C', 14.5)], 'ADBFGCE': [None, ('ADBFGC', 2.5), ('E', 17.0)], 'BFG': [('ADBFG', 2.0), ('BF', 5.75), ('G', 6.25)], 'AD': [('ADBFG', 4.25), ('A', 4.0), ('D', 4.0)]}
```

The output should be in the structure of something like `{"A":{"B":("AB",4)}}`, in the code above this is the dictionary 'CCAD'. I've literally been trying all night to do it but it's not working and I have no idea why.

Basically what I'm trying to do is to build a function that will output a dictionary of dictionaries where for each distinct pair of elements in the list `leaves` it will calculate an ancestor (I got some great help calculating that previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987377/how-to-make-this-recursive-function-iterative-in-python)) along with the distance, which in that link there would be a matter of keeping a running total each time the function iterates.

It's outputting a dictionary of dictionaries like I need, but it's not doing it for every pair, only certain ones. The 'tree' data structure is in that link too if you need to see it.

Any help is appreciated, I'm getting pretty desperate at this stage :/

Comment: Sample input and output?

Comment: The fix of *this* function is a too localized request. You should ask about a problem that you're facing. Please read the [faq].

Comment: on this line: `otu1,otu2,tree = tree[otu1][0][0],tree[otu2][0][0],tree` you are redefining `tree` as the same object. It is either an error or a useless assignement

Comment: Sorry guys, I'll rephrase it all in a minute, please check again. Sorry again, this has me extremely frustrated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I think you want to calculate the distances between every leaf node. So I'm having a go at solving your problem, not answering your question.

Your commonAncestor algorithm is flawed as it assumes that the leaf nodes are all at the same depth. They are not.

The first solution that springs to mind is to determine all of the leaf nodes and calculate the path to the root node for each of them. Determine the closest common ancestor by comparing both paths in reverse.

The output from this is a dictionary of pairs of nodes and the number of hops between them.

```
from itertools import combinations

data = {'A': [('AD', 4.0), None, None], 'C': [('ADBFGC', 14.5), None, None], 'B': [('BF', 0.5), None, None], 'E': [('ADBFGCE', 17.0), None, None], 'D': [('AD', 4.0), None, None], 'G': [('BFG', 6.25), None, None], 'F': [('BF', 0.5), None, None], 'ADBFG': [('ADBFGC', 6.25), ('AD', 4.25), ('BFG', 2.0)], 'BF': [('BFG', 5.75), ('B', 0.5), ('F', 0.5)], 'ADBFGC': [('ADBFGCE', 2.5), ('ADBFG', 6.25), ('C', 14.5)], 'ADBFGCE': [None, ('ADBFGC', 2.5), ('E', 17.0)], 'BFG': [('ADBFG', 2.0), ('BF', 5.75), ('G', 6.25)], 'AD': [('ADBFG', 4.25), ('A', 4.0), ('D', 4.0)]}

def get_path(tree,leaf):
  path = []
  location = leaf
  while True:
    path.append(location)
    parent = tree.get(location)[0]
    if parent:
      location = parent[0]
    else:
      break
  return path

def get_leaves(tree):
  return [ x for (x,y) in tree.items() if y[1] is None and y[2] is None ]

def leafDistances(tree):
  paths = {}
  leaves = get_leaves(tree)
  for leaf in leaves:
    paths[leaf] = get_path(tree,leaf)
  results = {}
  for l1,l2 in combinations(leaves,2):
    commonAncestor = [ x for (x,y) in zip(paths[l1][::-1],paths[l2][::-1]) if x == y ][-1]
    distance = paths[l1].index(commonAncestor) + paths[l2].index(commonAncestor)
    results[(l1,l2)] = distance
    print "%s <-> %s Ancestor == %s, distance == %s\nPath of %s == %s\nPath of %s == %s" % (l1,l2,commonAncestor,distance,l1,paths[l1],l2,paths[l2])
  return results

leafDistances(data)
```

This prints out for clarity:

```
A <-> C Ancestor == ADBFGC, distance == 4
Path of A == ['A', 'AD', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of C == ['C', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
A <-> B Ancestor == ADBFG, distance == 5
Path of A == ['A', 'AD', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of B == ['B', 'BF', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
A <-> E Ancestor == ADBFGCE, distance == 5
Path of A == ['A', 'AD', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of E == ['E', 'ADBFGCE']
A <-> D Ancestor == AD, distance == 2
Path of A == ['A', 'AD', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of D == ['D', 'AD', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
A <-> G Ancestor == ADBFG, distance == 4
Path of A == ['A', 'AD', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of G == ['G', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
A <-> F Ancestor == ADBFG, distance == 5
Path of A == ['A', 'AD', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of F == ['F', 'BF', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
C <-> B Ancestor == ADBFGC, distance == 5
Path of C == ['C', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of B == ['B', 'BF', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
C <-> E Ancestor == ADBFGCE, distance == 3
Path of C == ['C', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of E == ['E', 'ADBFGCE']
C <-> D Ancestor == ADBFGC, distance == 4
Path of C == ['C', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of D == ['D', 'AD', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
C <-> G Ancestor == ADBFGC, distance == 4
Path of C == ['C', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of G == ['G', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
C <-> F Ancestor == ADBFGC, distance == 5
Path of C == ['C', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of F == ['F', 'BF', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
B <-> E Ancestor == ADBFGCE, distance == 6
Path of B == ['B', 'BF', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of E == ['E', 'ADBFGCE']
B <-> D Ancestor == ADBFG, distance == 5
Path of B == ['B', 'BF', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of D == ['D', 'AD', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
B <-> G Ancestor == BFG, distance == 3
Path of B == ['B', 'BF', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of G == ['G', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
B <-> F Ancestor == BF, distance == 2
Path of B == ['B', 'BF', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of F == ['F', 'BF', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
E <-> D Ancestor == ADBFGCE, distance == 5
Path of E == ['E', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of D == ['D', 'AD', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
E <-> G Ancestor == ADBFGCE, distance == 5
Path of E == ['E', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of G == ['G', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
E <-> F Ancestor == ADBFGCE, distance == 6
Path of E == ['E', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of F == ['F', 'BF', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
D <-> G Ancestor == ADBFG, distance == 4
Path of D == ['D', 'AD', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of G == ['G', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
D <-> F Ancestor == ADBFG, distance == 5
Path of D == ['D', 'AD', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of F == ['F', 'BF', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
G <-> F Ancestor == BFG, distance == 3
Path of G == ['G', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
Path of F == ['F', 'BF', 'BFG', 'ADBFG', 'ADBFGC', 'ADBFGCE']
```

Comment: Wow, you put in a lot of work. Thanks, I'll run through this now and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Glad this was helpful to you. If you have huge datasets, then there are probably more efficient algorithms you could use. I was just aiming for functional.

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not give the desired output it's quite hard to debug the code, but I have a feeling that the last `if` condition should be under the `while`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't put in the final return statement at the end of the code. If you wouldn't mind having another look? Sorry again

Comment: since `tree` is not modified by this block it would be an infinite loop wouldn't it?

Comment: Well the whole point of the function is to extract certain information from 'tree' not to change it.